# Error in connecting to database using RSQLite

Tags: r, rsqlite

I encountered an error while I was trying to connect to database using RSQLite.
The following is my code:

```
 library(DBI)
  library(RSQLite)

  con = dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="C:/database/Forms/20183.sqlite")
  dbSendQuery(conn=con,
              "CREATE TABLE compsubm
              (FILENAME TEXT, COMLSUBFILE TEXT)")
```

And the error message is:

> Error in connection_connect(dbname, loadable.extensions, flags, vfs) :
>    Could not connect to database:
>   unable to open database file

I tried both R 3.5.1 and R 3.3.3, and, R studio is run as the administrator. Could you let me know how to fix this error?

Comment: Check if your user has read/write permissions on that file.

Comment: Can you please try `dbname="C:\\database\\Forms\\20183.sqlite"` ?